# nestjs not able access app running on local network on windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows-10, nestjs, windows-firewall, nestjs-config

I am unable to access NestJs app running on port 3000, I am running the app using this code:

```
  await app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function () {
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using the following method:

in start menu Search "Firewall & network protection" 
Choose "Allow an app through firewall" 
Click `Change Settings` button. 
Search for "Evented I/O for V8 Javascript" OR "Node.js: Server-side Javascript" and click the `public` checkmarks (see the SS below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your ENDPOINT in your frontend (http://localhost:3000  ---> http://myipbackend:3000)